Removing the constant from a summation through change of indexes
For $k>0$, $m>0$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$:First to bring $$\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+m}$$ under one denominator. That is getting $\frac{m}{k^2+km} = m\frac{1}{k(k+m}$. And then working with this sum for $n \geq m$: $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k(k+m)}$$ from which I've got \begin{align}
... &= \frac{1}{m} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{m}{k(k+m)} \\
&= \frac{1}{m} (\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} - \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k+m})
\end{align}
and now it is asked to somehow get it into the form of $$... = \sum_{k=1}^m a(k,n)$$ My attempt was to try something similar to $$\sum_{j=m+1}^{n+m} \frac{1}{j}$$ but it goes not much further to bring it to a desired state.
Is there something that I'm missing, so that it is possible to bring it into a(k,n) by change of index? Thank you in advance.

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k+m} = \sum_{j=1+m}^{n+m} \frac{1}{j} $$
corresponding to the change of index $j = k + m$.
Now, if $n \ge m$, the terms for $1+m \le k \le n$ cancel, leaving
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} - \sum_{k=1+m}^{n+m} \frac{1}{k} 
= \sum_{k=1}^{m} \frac{1}{k} - \sum_{k=n+1}^{n+m} \frac{1}{k}$$
Then using another change of index in the second sum, it's
$$ \sum_{k=1}^m \left(\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+n}\right)$$

Thank you for your answer. But I'm still not exactly sure how the cancelation part goes. How does $n \geq m$ guarantees, that $1+m \leq n$?

It doesn't.  In the case $n=m$, there are no terms to cancel.
